# Springboot Jsp not working with version 2.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, jar

I have a springboot application which is not working with JSP when i run inside intellij it works but when make a JAR it doesn't work. It gives this error.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>       This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon May 21 00:23:11 IST 2018
>       There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>       No message available

JSP files are present in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp.

And application.properties file contains.

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` is somewhat strange `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` (for .war) ...or even `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` (for .jar) would be "normal"

Comment: @xerx593 that did not worked for me.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: plz provide more infos: 1. regarding your maven&spring config 2. on how you run with intellij (project, run config) (somewhere in "the difference" is the root/core of your problem:)

Comment: @xerx593 I am using gradle, here is the build.gradle https://pastebin.com/N65tDvpa,

Comment: application.yml file contains spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /
      suffix: .jsp

Comment: index.jsp file are in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/

Comment: when i run gradle bootRun, it works like charm, but when i make a fat jar using gradle clean build it doesn't work

Comment: Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Are you using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` anywhere in your project?

Comment: @ anubhava i checked and i am not using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It related with how maven do JAR packaging.

"With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work (...). An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat."

You can check it by yourself - open generated JAR file and in root WEB-INF directory will be missing. This is the reason and the difference why in IDE is working fine and as JAR not.

Please read: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Solution: Make WAR not JAR :-)

Change packaging in your POM.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Next build project normally as usual:

```
mvn clean install
```

Run it:

```
java -jar target/app.war
```

Answer (score 1):

Last week, I was also having same issue, while I start the Springboot server from STS it was working fine as expected but when I start the same project from CLI then was getting error as:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available

Tried putting *WEB-INF* from webapp folder (/frontierSample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/*.jsp) manually after executing "mvn clean install", still was getting the same error.

But after changing the *packing* in pom.xml from **jar** to **war** it worked !